# How to avoid Name errors of object properties in kivy?

Tags: python, properties, kivy

I want to transfer a Value, that shows on a Button from python to kivy.
Sadly, I can't handle the Name Error of the Numeric Property "z".

I already tried putting the definition in the ButterLayout class instead, but the same error occured and I unsuccessfully tried for hours to find a solution in youtube tutorials and on kivy.org.

**In Python:**

```
class ButterLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ButterApp(App):
    zahl = NumericProperty(1)

    def build(self):
        return ButterLayout()


flApp = ButterApp()

flApp.run()
```

**In my .kv file:**

```
<ButterLayout>:
    zahl: z

    CustButton:
        text: str(z)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

---

Error Message:

zahl: z
 NameError: name 'z' is not defined

Comment: Like the error says, 'z' is not defined. There's nothing in your code that even tries to define it, so I think you have some misunderstanding. Please explain what you believe should be happening.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think that changing your `kv` file will help:

```
<ButterLayout>:
    CustButton:
        text: str(app.zahl)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```